# How to manage containerized applications settings?

Tags: java, containers, openshift

I have a bunch of containerized java applications on OpenShift server. Each has an applications.properties file where described the url's to databases and http servers.

So if I want to change one of that urls, I have to change 20+ application.properties files and redeploy 20+ applications.

How to sipmlify app properties management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to integrate applications with config server, e.g. it can be zookeeper. In case of spring cloud applications see [spring-cloud-zookeeper-config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-zookeeper/2.0.x/single/spring-cloud-zookeeper.html#spring-cloud-zookeeper-config), so it provide abilities to configure application settings individually or with common settings.
In addition, it provide multitenancy capabilities via different namespaces:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    zookeeper:
      config:
        enabled: true
        root: config/${spring.application.namespace}
```